# What is Electromagnetic Induced Transparency?

Tags: quantum-optics, quantum-electrodynamics

Please can anyone explain the concepts of [electromagnetic induced transparency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetically_induced_transparency)? I am having problem with the technicality of the explanation on wikipedia. Please I am an engineer with a physics background though and would love if this can be explained with little to no jargons . I am working on optical buffers and studying recent technologies and would love and explanation on this.

Answer (score 2):

As you may know, electromagnetic induced transparency (or EIT) is a technique for eliminating the effect of a medium on a propagating beam of electromagnetic radiation. To obtain transparency or to improve transmission, you have to apply two laser wavelengths whose frequencies differ by a Raman transition of a medium. From a classical point of view, you can eliminate the effect of a medium on a propagating beam by stopping the electrons to move at the frequencies of the applied field (i.e. if the electrons do not move, they do not contribute to the dielectric constant). This non-movement will happen if at each applied frequency, the electron is subjected to two sinusoidal forces of opposing phase. 
For a quantum mechanical treatment of the problem and other details I would suggest this article http://www.unl.edu/amop/pdf_files/RMP_EIT_Fleischhauer.pdf

Hope this helps.